# Connecting to MySQL from Workbench

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-workbench

MySQL remote access

I have a mysql database, running on Ubuntu Server 12.04 that I need to access remotely. For some reason this is become much more of a chore than I think it should be.

I have been through countless threads trying to resolve this issue with no luck what so ever. I do not have another linux box to test my connection. I am only using the MySQL Workbench from a Window 7 machine.

Here is what I have done so far:

- set the iptables to accept
- set the my.cnf to have the bind address of the server
- created a user for both localhost and %
- grant all to those users
- restarted mysql
- verified the user has all priv
- verified mysql is listening on 3306

give the correct setting to Workbench and I get 
"Your connection attempt failed for user 'USER' from your host to server at x.x.x.x:3306:
 Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (10061)"

EDIT: I did notice that it show 'localhost and NOT the ipaddress when I run this cmd, but i'm not sure how to change that, or if it is even the issue. Thoughts?

`# lsof -i -P | grep :3306`

`mysqld   5775    mysql   10u  IPv4 154265      0t0  TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)`

Comment: Did you open the port 3306 on your Win 7 machine?

Comment: Thats a good one. I would think that the install of workbench would do that on its own. The firewall is off on the Win7 machine.

Answer (score 2):

`vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Change the following line to reflect as below:

```
(bind-address            = 127.0.0.1)
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Close the file then and restart mysql

To verify that mysql port `3306` is listening on all interfaces:
`netstat -lnt | grep 3306`

You should see this:

```
tcp    0      0 0.0.0.0:3306         0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN
```

Answer (score 0):

> Find mysql config file (/etc/mysql/)
>   comment out the following line by putting a hash character in front of it as shown -> #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
>   -> Restart the server: sudo service mysql restart